# Excel Lambda Function returns #VALUE and will not SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, lambda, sumproduct

I have a lambda function which will not let itself be included in a `SUMPRODUCT` depending on the YEARS comparison. All other parts of the formula are working but stick the `LAMBDA` function result in there and it just won't have it... Why ???

Row `5` in blue are figures as a result of the lambda function based on a contract value broken into 2 parts for design and construction based on a % between 2 dates from initial start to end from cols `Q - X` not really relevant.

The lambda takes the result and spreads in across the months (col y onwards). Works fine but the annual sum columns `N - P` are summing fixed months in the spread (y onwards) and if the date changes in y4 the calcs are all wrong. So to make it dynamic in terms of the start date in Y4 columns `N - P` must look at the years in row `4` (and onwards) and add up the ones for the year. But change the spread calc Y5 onwards to speed up the sheet and the `SUMPRODUCT` does not work and returns `#VALUE`...

Can anyone help me on this please? I would post the sheet but it's a bit confidential.

Y4 formula:

```
=SPRDVAL(Y$4,$Q5,Z$4,$W5,$S5,$X5,$U5)
```

Lambda for `SPRDVAL`:

```
=LAMBDA(DATEP,OPD,DATEF,VWOF,SOS,VWON,COMD,
 IFERROR(IFS(AND(MONTH(DATEP)=MONTH(OPD),YEAR(DATEP)=YEAR(OPD)),
 (DATEF-OPD)*VWOF,AND(MONTH(SOS)=MONTH(DATEP),YEAR(SOS)=YEAR(DATEP)),
 (SOS-DATEP)*VWOF+(DATEF-SOS)*VWON,AND(MONTH(COMD)=MONTH(DATEP),
 YEAR(COMD)=YEAR(DATEP)),(COMD-DATEP)*VWON,AND(OPD<DATEP,SOS>DATEP),
 DAY(EOMONTH(DATEP,0))*VWOF,AND(SOS<DATEP,COMD>DATEP),
 DAY(EOMONTH(DATEP,0))*VWON,TRUE,""),"")
)
```

[image: Clip]

I have broken each of the parts of the formula in O5 and all work (inc `SUPRODUCT` of row `5` spread) but once they are combined... no joy.. Just a `#VALUE`

Told off for not posting cross post link...
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/excel-lambda-function-returns-value-and-will-not-sumproduct.1223280/#post-5982608

Comment: is it an issue with the format of your cell?

Comment: What is the connection between `LAMBDA` function and `SUMPRODUCT`?

Comment: I don't see how the format could be the issue, having a. tried every variation and b. the formats are the same.

Comment: The SUMPRODUCT is to sum the row of results from the LAMBDA function. They haven't met each other in real life outside of this sheet. ;)